# flutter injectable register subclasses types

Tags: flutter, dependency-injection, injectable

following code uses [injectable](https://pub.dev/packages/injectable) to configures getIt so when I ask for `A` in "prod" environment it gives me `ImplementedA` but i can't ask for `ImplementedA` explicitly.

for example when I am in "test" environment and i need `ImplementedA` for testing it. it's not accessible. any solution please?

```
abstract class A {}

@Injectable(as: A, env: ["prod"])
class ImplementedA extends A {}
```

for exmaple:
env : "prod"
getIt() => gives me ImplementedA
getIt() => Object/factory with type ImplementedA is not registered inside GetIt.

Answer (score 0):

You can't decide to inject a subtype of A. Because subtype of A is not injectable. You should inject A and the injection must decide what kind of subtype A will give.

If you need especially ImplementedA, you have to mark it as @injectable too. (not as: A). Otherwise, you could specific methods move to in A class which extended